# how to rename a file when ouputted in foreach loop

Tags: php, rename

For a filemanagement system i use a foreach loop for outputting all the files and folders in directories.
Now i want to rename the files and folders via a form. 
My code looks like this:

```
/* RENDER THE FILES */
foreach ($files as $file) {
.....
<td>

        <?php
        // FILENAME
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {


        echo '<div class="sfmfolder">'.$file.'</div><br />';                                         
        }
        else {          
        echo '<div class="sfmfile">'.$file.'</div>';                        
        }

        ?>

    </td>
    <td>
    <?php
        // RENAME
        if($_POST['renamefile']) {

        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){
            rename($dir.'/'.$file, $dir.'/'.$_POST['rename']);
        }
        else {
            rename($dir.'/'.$file,       $dir.'/'.$_POST['rename'].'.'.$FileExtension);
        }

    }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">

        <input type="text" name="rename" />
        <input type="submit" name="renamefile" value="go" />

    </form>
    </td>
```

My problem is: renaming a file renames all other files also with that name including the folders.
How to achieve that only the correct file only will be renamed?
I know the problem is that all files outputted via the foreeach loop

`$dir.'/'.$file` gives the path to the file or folder

`$file` is the name of the file or folder

Comment: This code is wide open to path attacks. You want to add protection against that.

Comment: oke but that was not my question. How can i catch one file and rename that certain file only?

Comment: You seem to know what if statements are. Did you know you can compare 2 strings using `==`, `===`, [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php), [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php), and various other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a dirty solution is to add a hidden field to your form that contains the orginal name of the file **and to move the if condition out of the loop** somthing like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="rename" />
    <input type="hidden" name="orginalfilename" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="renamefile" value="go" />
</form>

<?php
    // RENAME
    if($_POST['renamefile'] && $_POST['orginalfilename']) {
    $file = $_POST['orginalfilename'];
    if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){
        rename($dir.'/'.$file, $dir.'/'.$_POST['rename']);
    }
    else {
        rename($dir.'/'.$file,       $dir.'/'.$_POST['rename'].'.'.$FileExtension);
    }

}
?>
```